# What maven dependency do I need to get FileCredentialStore?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, google-analytics-api

I want to get access to google-analytics via the java api (v3). For logging in I want to use OAuth2. I found a java example, that shows how to do it. Unfortunately I am not able to compile the code I copied. It seems that I have no dependency for `FileCredentialStore`. My Pom looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.import.google</groupId>
  <artifactId>analyticsImporter</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <name>Analytics Importer</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-analytics</artifactId>
      <version>v3-rev41-1.14.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>v2-rev36-1.14.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the dependency for the [Java 6 (and higher) Extensions to the Google OAuth Client Library for Java](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-java6/1.14.1-beta) artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

It does have the class [`FileCredentialStore`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-java6/1.11.0-beta/com/google/api/client/extensions/java6/auth/oauth2/FileCredentialStore.java).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but this does not solve my problem. It still does not find the class.

Comment: Indeed, you've got to add the dependency to `google-oauth-client-java6`, which has the extensions in the `com.google.api.client.extensions` package.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the maven dependency for OAuth2 which actually contains the FileCredentialStore class. Check if this works?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-java6</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but this does not provide me FileCredentialStore.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this one

```
google-oauth-client-java6 or google-oauth-client-java6
```

I recommend to use http://grepcode.com . Just search for the class name.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/source/browse/google-oauth-client-servlet/pom.xml?spec=svna58925931bd9cae29418431d0a63b9eb675fddc9&r=a58925931bd9cae29418431d0a63b9eb675fddc9

http://javadoc.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.11.0-beta/com/google/api/client/extensions/java6/auth/oauth2/FileCredentialStore.html

google-oauth-client-servlet contains FileCredentialStore class